# How do I add a unique constraint for a column that only needs to be unique when combined with another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

Okay so let's say I want to create two tables and match them with a foreign key:

```
    Table #1 Series
    Col 1: Series number (unique, primary key)
    Col 2: Series name
    Col 3: Series published date

    Table #2 Episodes
    Col 1: Series number (not unique in this table, foreign key, referenced with col1 of series table)
    Col 2: Episode number 
    Col 3: Episode name
```

Now Col2 of Table Episodes cannot be uniqe (because every series has a first, second, etc episode) but it does need to be unique when concated with col1. In other words, I want my constraint to allow this:

```
    Row 1: Series number 1, Episode number 1; Row 2: Series number 2, Episode number 1
```

but NOT allow this:

```
    Row 1: Series number 1, Episode number 1; Row 2: Series number 1, Episode number 1
```

I don't know how to do it. I can't have a unique constraint on the episode # column but I want to avoid seeing duplicate episode numbers matched to the same series number.

Of course this could be solved with javascript at the client end (where the data is being submitted) but I think that would be a hackeneyed solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index on more than 1 column:

```
alter table Episodes add unique index(Seriesnumber, Episodenumber);
```

Comment: how does that work exactly? does it create another column with auto-incrementing unique numbers? but how does that work as a constraint? what is the syntax for doing this at the table creation stage? also, what would the syntax be when i wanted to make a select from this data?

Comment: Unique index is an index, not a column. So every time you modify the data in those 2 columns (add a new row, update a row, etc), it modifies the index and check if it's still unique. Selection from that table is not affected.

Comment: right, i just had a brain fart sorry. so the advantage of having a multi-field unique index is that mysql would throw an error whenever i tried to insert values that were not unique across those two fields?

Comment: Cool, that's what I want. Can I ask you this though: how does unique index work across three fields? If just one of those three fields is unique, all three will pass as unique, right? It won't throw an error if two fields have already been used, so long as at least one is unique all three will pass .. am I correct in thinking that?

Comment: It's a combination of all the fields in the index that has to be unique as compared to all other combinations of the same fields in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX some_name ON Episodes(col1, col2);
```

Its called composite key or index.